# How to handle data output in an Observer?

Tags: java, android, exception, multithreading, observer-pattern

I have an `Observable` and an `Observer`. The observable does download some stuff in a background thread and calls `notifyObservers` to let the observers read the status.

At some point in `public void update` the observer tries to updates the GUI

```
((TextView)findViewById('R.id.foo')).setText("bar");
```

but it seems like the observable thread calls this method, because the Observable (!!!) throws this:

```
 android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
 at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2462)
 at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:512)
 ...
 at com.mynamespace.acitivty.TrackActivity.startPlay(TrackActivity.java:72)
 at com.mynamespace.acitivty.TrackActivity.update(TrackActivity.java:107)
 at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:147)
 at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:128)
 at com.mynamespace.module.communication.Download.stateChanged(Download.java:213)
 at com.mynamespace.module.communication.Download.run(Download.java:186)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1058)
```

Is there some way I can prevent this from happening? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your issue is similar to this one: [Android:android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException - How to solve the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536654/androidandroid-view-viewrootcalledfromwrongthreadexception-how-to-solve-the-p)

As **bhatt4982** answers there, you can use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). From its doc:

"There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.".

The answer from **AshtonBRSC** is also good, you can enclose your UI update in a Runnable and use the [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) Activity's method.