# android programming how to handle onclick() events when the program is running a different thread which is running as a server?

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, handler, buttonclick

I have a thread running the server sends a data to a client and receives a data from the client.

the server/client program am running is a modifed version of

code found at
 [Connecting 2 Emulator instances In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683854/connecting-2-emulator-instances-in-android)

After that happens . If a press a button. I need to perform some onclick events. But my program is receiving some
    Android:android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException

I looked and found tht we should use handler for these errors.
But am not sure how to combine a handler with an onclick() event function ?

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536654/androidandroid-view-viewrootcalledfromwrongthreadexception-how-to-solve-the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) simplest way, no need to manage Handler for thread, **put your server/client code in Asynctask's doInBackground()** so your UI also not be blocked.

Look at [Android Development: Implementing a simple Client-Server model](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/)

Thanks.. :-)